# Is it possible to integrate nvcc with gcc/g++ in windows?

Tags: gcc, cuda, mingw-w64, nvcc

I would linke to know if it is possible to use gcc/g++ as the c/c++ compiler in windows based CUDA? Furthermore, how can I compile fortran together with nvcc?
I am running CUDA 10.2 and the mingw gcc 8.1.0.

Comment: No it is not possible. The CUDA toolkit on windows is Visual studio only

Comment: Thanks. I will try MSVC.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible.  The only [supported host compiler for use with CUDA on windows](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements) is cl.exe, the compiler that ships with visual studio C++.

If you use the WSL2 environment on windows, then you [can use](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html) gcc/g++ with CUDA in that linux-like environment.

Comment: Got it. So I will stop struggle on this topic. Move forward with cl. Thanks